# Points/Commas in mathematical formulas

Tags: mathematics

the following question. I have a lot of mathematical formulas and equations in my thesis and now I was wondering if equations are separated with dots or commas. Would option 1 or 2 be correct now?
See here:
[Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yES1S.png)

Comment: Depends on where in a sentence an equation is.

Answer (score 3):

There are already many other questions on this forum that address this (which should also be easy to find), but the short answer is that formulas are treated as a regular part of the text, whether or not you offset them into their own lines. So, if you would add a comma or period if the formula was printed as part of the regular flow of text, you should add a comma or period in the same way if you offset the formula onto its own line.